# linq query expression for "left outer join" with a default if right side is null

Tags: .net, linq

I'm controlling the visibility and order of columns in a datagrid that I myself made (from scratch). This is a custom object model for a usercontrol. I want to return all my columns for display purposes, but in the order specified by some column layout classes and only if the corresponding column layout's visible property is true. I'm configuring the layout on an exception basis so that I only need to specify the columns that need to be ordered or hidden.

`BrowsableProperties` is just a property that gets a subset of the properties of a type, which I'm holding in `Schema.Type`, and that's the source of the column set. A `GridLayout`, which is stored in the `Layout` property, holds many `TypeLayout`s, which hold many `ColumnLayout`s. A `TypeLayout` has a Type. `TypeLayout` exists because the very same grid can load many collections for different types during it's lifetime, and keep changing columns accordingly. It's a generic grid.

The `ColumnLayout`s go along with the properties, but there may not be a `ColumnLayout` for every property. If there isn't, I want to use the `ColumnLayout` returned by `ColumnLayout.Default`, but I can't get that "left outer join but if it's null use this default" logic working.

The following fetching function for columns is only returning the ones like an inner join, and I can't find where I can insert the default logic or the left join logic.

```vb
  Private Function GetColumns() As List(Of Column)
    Return (
        From PropertyInfo As PropertyInfo
        In BrowsableProperties
        From TypeLayout As TypeLayout In Layout.Types
        From ColumnLayout As ColumnLayout In TypeLayout.Columns
        Where TypeLayout.Type Is Schema.Type AndAlso
        ColumnLayout.Name = PropertyInfo.Name AndAlso
        ColumnLayout.Visible
        Select PropertyInfo,
        ColumnLayout
        Order By
          ColumnLayout.Order,
          PropertyInfo.Name).
        Select(Function(x, i) New Column(Me, i, x.PropertyInfo)
    ).ToList
  End Function
```

Here's the `GridLayout` class:

```vb
<Serializable()> _
Public Class GridLayout
  Inherits DatabaseObject

  <XmlAttribute()> _
  Public Property Context As String

  Private _Types As List(Of TypeLayout)
  Public ReadOnly Property Types As List(Of TypeLayout)
    Get
      If _Types Is Nothing Then
        _Types = New List(Of TypeLayout)
      End If
      Return _Types
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

Here's the `TypeLayout` class:

```vb
<Serializable()>
Public Class TypeLayout
  Inherits DatabaseObject

  Private _Columns As List(Of ColumnLayout)
  Public ReadOnly Property Columns As List(Of ColumnLayout)
    Get
      If _Columns Is Nothing Then
        _Columns = New List(Of ColumnLayout)
      End If
      Return _Columns
    End Get
  End Property

  <XmlIgnore()> _
  Public Property Type As System.Type

  <XmlAttribute("Type")> _
  Public Property TypeName As String
    Get
      Return Type.AssemblyQualifiedName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      Type = Type.GetType(value)
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

and the `ColumnLayout` class:

```vb
<Serializable()>
Public Class ColumnLayout
  Inherits DatabaseObject

  <XmlAttribute()> _
  Public Property Name As String

  <XmlAttribute()> _
  Public Property Order As Integer = Integer.MaxValue

  <XmlAttribute()> _
  Public Property [ReadOnly] As Boolean = False

  <XmlAttribute()> _
  Public Property Visible As Boolean = True

  Public Shared ReadOnly [Default] As New ColumnLayout With
    {.Order = Integer.MaxValue,
    .ReadOnly = False,
    .Visible = True}

End Class
```

and here's a typical configuration:

```xml
<GridLayout xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Context="frmApplication/TabControl1/tpHelpDesk/HelpDesk1/grdTickets">
<Types>
<TypeLayout Type="Simmons.BusinessObjects.HelpDesk.Ticket, Simmons.BusinessObjects, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
<Columns>
<ColumnLayout Name="TID" Order="0" ReadOnly="false" Visible="true"/>
<ColumnLayout Name="DatabaseState" Order="2147483647" ReadOnly="false" Visible="false"/>
<ColumnLayout Name="Loaded" Order="2147483647" ReadOnly="false" Visible="false"/>
</Columns>
</TypeLayout>
</Types>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it in two statements. My original question, of how to do it in one statement, remains unanswered.

*(sorry about the vb. The language translators were supposed to work for the construct program - but there was way too much linq to decode my Matrix)*

```vb
  Private Function GetColumns() As List(Of Column)
    Dim ColumnLayouts = From TypeLayout As TypeLayout In Layout.Types
                        From ColumnLayout As ColumnLayout In TypeLayout.Columns
                        Where TypeLayout.Type = Schema.Type
                        Select ColumnLayout

    Return (From PropertyInfo As PropertyInfo
          In BrowsableProperties
          Group Join ColumnLayout As ColumnLayout In ColumnLayouts.DefaultIfEmpty(ColumnLayout.Default)
          On PropertyInfo.Name Equals ColumnLayout.Name
          Into ColumnLayoutDefaults = Group
          From ColumnLayout In ColumnLayoutDefaults.DefaultIfEmpty(ColumnLayout.Default)
          Where ColumnLayout.Visible
          Order By ColumnLayout.Order).
          Select(Function(FromClause, Index) New Column(Me, FromClause.PropertyInfo, FromClause.ColumnLayout, Index)).
          ToList

  End Function
```